# How to change the font color of a disabled TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Does anyone know which property sets the text color for disabled control? 
I have to display some text in a disabled `TextBox` and I want to set its color to black.

Comment: answer from Cheeta is correct. Consider reflagging?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**NOTE:** see Cheetah's answer below as it identifies a prerequisite to get this solution to work.  Setting the `BackColor` of the `TextBox`.

---

I think what you really want to do is enable the `TextBox` and set the `ReadOnly` property to `true`.

It's a bit tricky to change the color of the text in a disabled `TextBox`.  I think you'd probably have to subclass and override the `OnPaint` event.

`ReadOnly` though should give you the same result as `!Enabled` and allow you to maintain control of the color and formatting of the `TextBox`.  I think it will also still support selecting and copying text from the `TextBox` which is not possible with a disabled `TextBox`.

Another simple alternative is to use a `Label` instead of a `TextBox`.

Comment: If this is your answer go ahead and click the check for me :)

Comment: It's not an exact answer but it's a fair alternative;)

Comment: that's true, feel free to change it to a more exact answer if one pops up.

Comment: I'll do it if I will continue to look for the exact answer.

Comment: This only works if you want the color black.  It still won't let you use the Foreground property to control the color.

Answer (score 60):

Additionally, in order for ForeColor to be obeyed on a TextBox marked ReadOnly, you must explicitly set the BackColor.  If you want to have it still use the default BackColor, you have to make the set explicit, as the designer is too smart for its own good here.  It is sufficient to set the BackColor to its current value.  I do this in the Load event for the form, like so:

```
private void FormFoo_Load(...) {
    txtFoo.BackColor = txtFoo.BackColor;
}
```

Comment: IIRC, there is a flag somewhere to check if the colors have been customized.  That flag doesn't get set unless the BackColor is set.  I can't find it now, but if you rummage around in Reflector, you might be able to.

Answer (score 7):

I've just found a great way of doing that. In my example I'm using a RichTextBox but it should work with any Control:

```
public class DisabledRichTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
{
    // See: http://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages

    private const int WM_SETFOCUS   = 0x07;
    private const int WM_ENABLE     = 0x0A;
    private const int WM_SETCURSOR  = 0x20;

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (!(m.Msg == WM_SETFOCUS || m.Msg == WM_ENABLE || m.Msg == WM_SETCURSOR))
            base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

You can safely set Enabled = true and ReadOnly = false, and it will act like a label, preventing focus, user input, cursor change, without being actually disabled.

See if it works for you.
Greetings

Answer (score 5):

hi 
set the readonly attribute to true from the code side or run time not from the design time

```
txtFingerPrints.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Info;
txtFingerPrints.ReadOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.
Override the OnPaint event of the TextBox.

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
     SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor); //Use the ForeColor property
     // Draw string to screen.
     e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, drawBrush, 0f,0f); //Use the Font property
}
```

set the ControlStyles to "UserPaint"

```
public MyTextBox()//constructor
{
     // This call is required by the Windows.Forms Form Designer.
     this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint,true);

     InitializeComponent();

     // TODO: Add any initialization after the InitForm call
}
```

[Refrence](http://www.syncfusion.com/FAQ/WindowsForms/FAQ_c94c.aspx#q1121q)

Or you can try this hack

In Enter event set the focus

```
int index=this.Controls.IndexOf(this.textBox1);

this.Controls[index-1].Focus();
```

So your control will not focussed and behave like disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display text that cannot be edited or selected you can simply use a label

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @spoon16 and @Cheetah, I always set the `tabstop` property to False on the textbox to prevent the text from being selected by default.

Alternatively, you can also do something like this:

```
private void FormFoo_Load(...) {
    txtFoo.Select(0, 0);
}
```

or

```
private void FormFoo_Load(...) {
    txtFoo.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

Comment: Setting TabStop to false is important to avoid read only control accidentally getting focus.

Answer (score 1):

Just handle Enable changed and set it to the color you need

```
private void TextBoxName_EnabledChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the 'Read Only' as 'True' is the easiest method.