# VB.net - Change Background of Disabled Form Element

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have a rich text box that I want to show as un-editable and un-selectable text. If I set Read-Only to **YES** and Enabled to **NO**, then I get the desired effect...

...except disabling the control changes the background color to the washed out grey. I'd like to keep the background color white.

I have tried:

```
RichTextBox.BackColor = Color.White
```

but that doesn't appear to do anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the background color of a rich text box when it is disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946139/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-rich-text-box-when-it-is-disabled)

Comment: No, that link is for C#, but it did help me find the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite a duplicate of the other post, but @Hans' link provided me with the solution:

```
Private Sub RichTextSummaryBox_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextSummaryBox.Enter
    ARandomControl.Focus() 'I use a picturebox of the company logo
End Sub
```