# change textcolor of read only text box c#

Tags: c#, textbox, readonly

I have textBox1 which is read only. I am trying to change

```
textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

But it does not work. Any idea ?

Comment: Found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276179/how-to-change-the-font-color-of-a-disabled-textbox , might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

When you set the property of a `TextBox` control to `ReadOnly` true the text becomes grayed out. That's the default behavior.

If you have a requirement to show it in Red, then you shouldn't set the `ReadOnly` property but rather handle the `TextChanged` events manually and keep the old value intact. But i don't recommend it.

Comment: @BrianSnow - Well, because it tends to get messy if you start working in the code-behind rather than having your UI encapsulated and loosely coupled to the logic behind.

Comment: A better approach would be to have the texbox with the behavior you want as a custom control (in case you intend on reusing it)

Comment: A simpler solution is just to set the textbox BackColor to itself. that is textBox1.BackColor = textBox1.BackColor; textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red; textBox1.ReadOnly = true;  This sets the colors to custom

Answer (score 1):

Try to cancel the event for KeyPress:

```
textBox1.Text = "Test";
textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
textBox1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textBox1_KeyPress);

void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
 e.Handled = true;
}
```

ReadOnly property always greyed the control out. This is default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do to a read-only textbox is (first change it to read/write) you can override the `KeyPress()` event of the said `TextBox` and ignore all the inputs from there onwards.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
textBox1.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control);
textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a RichTextBox. When it is read only, it continue displaying the text in the color

Answer (score -1):

This should help you.

```
textboxname.ForeColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.selectanycolor);
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. Please see our help centre, particularly http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. In particular, could you please edit your answer to explain how and why this solves the asker's problem?