# Change a textbox colour when disabled C#

Tags: c#, textbox

i am going to ask the same thing like other topic which I have seen.

When i use the Textbox.Enable or Textbox.readOnly, the textbox gets a dark colour, how can i change this colour for a better colour? (white could be better).

Comment: If you've seen the same question before, why ask it again? What were the answers to the duplicate questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a TextBox is disabled, it ignores the `ForeColor`.  You can override this by implementing your custom painting.

From the source [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276179/how-to-change-the-font-color-of-a-disabled-textbox):-

You can override the OnPaint event like something like this:-

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
     SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor);
     // Draw string to screen.
     e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, drawBrush, 0f,0f); 
}
set the ControlStyles to "UserPaint"

public MyTextBox()//constructor
{
     // This call is required by the Windows.Forms Form Designer.
     this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint,true);

     InitializeComponent();

     // TODO: Add any initialization after the InitForm call
}
```

Comment: how can i do? can u give an example(code)?

Comment: I have updated my answer... Check if this helps you!!!! :)

Comment: @user2698690:- Did that worked for  you???

Answer (score 0):

Override OnPaint method by customizing the textbox.
Also, you could see this : [How to change the font color of a disabled TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276179/how-to-change-the-font-color-of-a-disabled-textbox)