# How to change the fore color of a disabled multiline TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a multiline Text Box. How can I change the fore color when it is disabled ?

I fond a solution here 
[Change a textbox colour when disabled C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328024/change-a-textbox-colour-when-disabled-c-sharp/18328077#18328077)

But, when MultiLine is true, it is a little bit complicated to find out currently visible portion of the text (i.e. currently visible lines and characters).

So any one know how to play with WM_CTLCOLOREDIT and WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC messages to change the fore color of Text Box in C#.NET ? 
OR
How to change the fore color of a disabled Text Box without overriding

```
OnPaint()
```

method ?

Comment: Finally, I decided to override `OnPaint()` and draw the text by calculating the current scroll position and all.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using enbled property of textbox why dont you use keypress event

```
private bool isDisabled = false;

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDisabled == true)
        {
            e.KeyChar = (char)0;
        }

    }
```

you can change the fore color everytime isDisable = true

Hope it Helps

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This will be my 3rd option. As I am customizing the appearance of System.Windows.Forms.TextBox to create a common control, am looking for a kind of handling notification messages and setting HBrush or some thing like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do:

```
richTextBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
```

or if you want to use black color, you have to use this trick:

```
richTextBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0,0,0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you make it simple?

Keep the `textBox` enabled, and set both `foreground` and `background` colors as you want them. And if you want that the user can not focus it, then use the event `textBox.Focused` to detect its focusing, as the event raises, set any other control to focus by programming.

Comment: Terrible idea! What if two controls does this? or what if all controls does this ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You can set the `tag` property and can verify what is the current condition of the control is. There is not the only way to do a thing, there are many ways. And all are correct. It is also a solution of the problem.

Comment: @Shaharyar: Thank you for the suggestion. I am customizing the TextBox control. So it is not possible to use this `tag` property and the workarounds. I am looking for a most preferable solution.