# How to disable a textbox without fading text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

Is there anyway of getting all of the properties of a `!enabled` `textbox` except the faded text?

I cannot use a `Label` because I want the `textbox` to be `enabled` eventually. I cannot use `readonly` because I do not want the user's cursor to appear within.

Comment: I think that setting the BackColor to a fixed color is a solution.

Comment: Which UI framework are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a SystemColor instead of KnownColor:

```
Color color = textbox1.BackColor ;
textbox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);

color = textbox1.ForeColor ;
textbox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
```

Comment: This does allow you to change the BackColor from fading but it does not stop the text within the textbox from fading.

Comment: Same thing for the ForeColor : I added the instructions in the proposed code.

Answer (score 3):

It would be best to have both a `Label` and a `TextBox` in the same location.

Hide the `TextBox` and display the content in a `Label` until you are ready to edit it.
At that point, hide the `Label` and show the `TextBox`.

Otherwise you'll have to subclass the `TextBox`, and override the `OnPaint` method, somewhat like the following:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
     SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor); //Use the ForeColor property
     // Draw string to screen.
     e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, drawBrush, 0f,0f); //Use the Font property
}
```

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6214818/2169762) and this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/de63a4e2-f453-49b3-ab0a-c338080681f0/how-to-change-a-disabled-textboxs-forecolor?forum=winforms).

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I wouldn't have to create a custom textbox. I actually was thinking about using a label and textbox. I was hoping there was something _very_ simple.